# How to add hidden data on Apple Push Notification

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-build

I'm using this Ruby script to send push notifications:

```
APNS.host = 'gateway.push.apple.com' 
APNS.port = 2195 
APNS.pem  = 'CERTIFICATE_PATH
APNS.pass = '56895689aA'
device_token = TOKEN
APNS.send_notification(device_token, :alert => 'Message', :badge => 1, :sound =>     'beep.wav')
```

And I'm handling it from the device like this (its Phonegap)

```
onAPNNotification: function (event) {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    if (event.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }
    if (event.badge) {
        console.log("Set badge on  " + pushNotification);
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(this.onGCMRegisterSuccess, event.badge);
    }
    if (event.sound) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, I recieve the notifications, but I would like to know if there's anyway to hide data so it won't be displayed when the notification arrives (and shows an alert with some text from the notification).

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The payload in the example uses an aps dictionary to request that the device display an alert message with an Close button on the left and a localized title for the “action” button on the right side of the alert. In this case, “PLAY” is used as a key into the Localizable.strings file for the currently selected language to get the localized equivalent of “Play”. The aps dictionary also requests that the application icon be badged with the number 5.

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
    },
    "badge" : 5,
},
"acme1" : "bar",
"acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

For more info: [Apple Dev](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21)